# Magento custom shipping module translations

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I created a custom shipping module which is working.
I want to set the 2 texts displayed on the checkout page to come from a translation file.

config.xml

```
<default>
    <carriers>
      <starmall>
           <active>1</active>
           <model>Starmall_Shippingcost_Model_Carrier_Starmall</model>
           <title>Carrier Title</title>
           <name>Method Name</name>
           <price>0.00</price>
           <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
        </starmall>
     </carriers>
</default>
```

Admin screen:

[image]

Checkout frontend screen:

[image]

QUESTION: I want to set the "aaa" and "bbb" texts in code to come from a translation file.

I can set the "aaa" text in code using
 `$method->setMethodTitle(Mage::helper("starmall_config")->__("Starmall_shipping_method_title"));`

Which then displays this:

[image]

**How can I set the "bbb" text in code?**

The following does not work:

```
        $method->setCarrierTitle("xxxxxx");
        $method->setTitle("xxxxx");
```

Comment: As alternate way you can set store wise title and method name from left dropdown select your store and add new title by store.

Answer (score 1):

Yes use translation function !

```
    $method->setCarrierTitle( Mage::helper('core')->__('string1') );
    $method->setTitle(Mage::helper('core')->__('string2'));
```

Then add this string to your translation CSV file !